# Column in SQL writes for too many times

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a query which shows the name of the guys(Angajat.nume and Angajat.prenume) and the salary (Angajat.salar) working at a restaurant (Restau.nume) and instead of writing it for 5 times, it writes for 25 times. I have 5 workers(id_a) and 1 restaurant(id_r) and 5 menu(id_m). How can I make it to show only for 5 times and keep the Meniu table in the query?

[My Relations and Data Base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRYgF.png)

[My Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtWZL.png)

```
SELECT        
    Restau.nume, Angajat.nume AS Expr1, Angajat.prenume
FROM
    Restau 
INNER JOIN
    Meniu ON Restau.id_r = Meniu.id_r 
INNER JOIN
    Angajat ON Restau.id_r = Angajat.id_r
```

Comment: post code  ,... not image

Comment: Why do you need the menue table when you're not using it? You can simply add `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates. But check with `select * from` to see if it's actually 25 different rows.

Comment: Distinct or group by. If menu doesn't relate to the query went keep it in?

Comment: Because I had the same problem with another query, it had to show a column for 20 times but instead it showed for 720 times. It is working fine with <code>SELECT DISTINCT</code> Thanks guys!

Comment: Why do you need `Meniu` in the query if you're not using any of it's columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  are using an unuseful join

```
SELECT        
        Restau.nume
        , Angajat.nume AS Expr1
        , Angajat.prenume
FROM    Restau 
INNER JOIN Angajat ON Restau.id_r = Angajat.id_r
```

add distinct if you have duplicated result

```
SELECT  DISTINCT      
        Restau.nume
        , Angajat.nume AS Expr1
        , Angajat.prenume
FROM    Restau 
INNER JOIN Angajat ON Restau.id_r = Angajat.id_r
```